# javascript regular expression to match a word and followed by digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to match a word exactly and immediatly followed by some digits in javascript.

In the below example url, i have to match exactly -t followed by digits 10, digits may change.

in the below url, it should match -t and 10.

priceangels.com/mouse-pads-t10.html

another example url :priceangels.com/apple-t275.html, here it should match -t followed by 275.

please help me with explanation.

Comment: What have you tried ? Here's a good site for testing regular expressions: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var regex = /-t\d+/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regular expression:

```
.*-t([\d]+).*
```

Answer (score 0):

this will satisfy for words other than `t` also, like

`qwertu10` in 
`priceangels.com/mouse-pads-qwertu10.html`

`baba10` in `priceangels.com/mouse-pads-baba10.html`

```
/(?=\-)-(\w+\d+)/g
```

demo here http://regex101.com/r/jN7wK2